# Intelli j not recognized some spring tag

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

[image: My code]

I'm wondering why occur this situation?

Comment: attach the image properly next time. I already edit it for you

Comment: sorry. I sign up now. so use difficulty.

Comment: You need to add the spring jars to your classpath. Do you have a build file?

Comment: You are missing the dependencies. It has nothing to do with Intellij.

Comment: thank you. but....Despite this situation, it is working....